# Change UITextField responder on Max Length

Tags: ios, swift

I have login controller where it has two textFields:

- Access Card
- Password

The Max Length for the access card is 9 and once the user type the ninth number, it should appear on the access card filed then the cursor needs to move to the password field.

In my code, the cursor is moving when the user clicks to enter the ninth number but the number doesn't appear and the cursor moves to the password field.

For example: I want to enter "123456789" as access card. Once I click "9" it doesn't appear but the cursor moves to password field:

LoginController.swift:

```
let ACCESSCARD_MAXLENGTH = 9
let PASSWORD_MAXLENGTH = 12
var AccessCardtextFieldLength = 0
var PasswordTextFieldLength = 0

class LoginViewController: UIViewController , UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var AccessCardTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var PasswordTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       // calling the function that initialize textFields
       initializeTextFields()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    }

     // function is used to initialize textFields
    func initializeTextFields () {

        // To set the focus on the access card once the view load.
        AccessCardTextField.becomeFirstResponder()


        // This must be defined so we can apply the text field functions on it
        AccessCardTextField.delegate = self
        PasswordTextField.delegate = self


        // Define the keyboard type of the textFields.
        AccessCardTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.NumberPad
        PasswordTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.ASCIICapable

    }


func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


         AccessCardtextFieldLength = (textField.text?.characters.count)! + string.characters.count
         PasswordTextFieldLength = (textField.text?.characters.count)! + string.characters.count
        if (textField == AccessCardTextField){
            for i in 0..<ACCESSCARD_MAXLENGTH{
                if (AccessCardtextFieldLength == ACCESSCARD_MAXLENGTH){
                    PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
                else{
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }

        }
        if (textField == PasswordTextField){
            return PasswordTextFieldLength <= PASSWORD_MAXLENGTH ? true : false

        }

        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: did your code execute `PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()` when you add breakpoint?

Comment: Yes it did, I added breakpoint to the PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder() but the code didn't stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool` will only update when it return true. In this case you are changing the `firstResponder` therefore it is not updated.

My suggestion is to use add target for this case. This is what you can do:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

   // calling the function that initialize textFields
   initializeTextFields()
   accessCardTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(LoginViewController.accessCardTextFieldChanged(_:)), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
}

func accessCardTextFieldChanged(textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text?.characters.count == ACCESSCARD_MAXLENGTH {
        modelTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

This way, it save you quite a few line of code. Most importantly, only accessCardTextField changed will be call. You could do another function to check your password textfield length separately. Also, i renamed from `AccessCardTextField` to `accessCardTextField`. It is recommended to have variable starting with lower case.

Comment: Your code gives an error "cannot call value of non-function type UITextField"

Comment: Sorry, when i was replacing it with your variable i accidentally deleted the `.addTarget`. I have updated it, try this.

Answer (score -1):

Not very sure if this works, but try edit your if statement contents with this.

```
if (AccessCardtextFieldLength == ACCESSCARD_MAXLENGTH){
      if (textField == AccessCardTextField) {
           textField.resignFirstResponder()
           PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In this condition

```
if (AccessCardtextFieldLength == ACCESSCARD_MAXLENGTH){
    PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    **return true**
}
else{
    return true
}
```

you returning flase that's why it doesn't show your last Character.

Comment: AccessCardTextField will not updated on last edit, try your self before posting